# Log in to terminal server directly

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, remote-desktop-services

Is it possible to allow particular domain users to log in to a terminal server directly if the server is part of a terminal server farm?

Environment: 3 x Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Do you mean log in to a specific terminal server rather than connecting to the farm and being directed to any one of the servers? If so, have you tried connecting to the server by name or ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should only be reserved for admins as you want your regular users going through the farm with a broker and DNS round robin setup.

**To do this as an admin click Start > Type MSTSC /admin > Hit Enter**

**Alternatively you can click Start+R > Type MSTSC /admin > Hit Enter**

**And finally, you can open Remote Desktop Connection and type he computer name you want followed by /admin to login to the specified server.**

[See this for more info.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-line-parameters-remote-desktop-connection#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

With NLB, no, however administrators can target individual servers by using mstsc /admin.  If you have a hardware load balancer, regular users most likely can target individual servers (depends on how the VIP is setup).

That said, targeting individual servers is usually a flawed design. I would avoid this, as it usually means there is not proper redundancy for an app, or the load may not be properly distributed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The reason I was looking at this is due to a stupid program that requires a CD to run. It won't even run from an ISO attached to the virtual server.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I believe this can be done via a TS Session Broker Load Balancing.